# Serving Static resources from file system | Spring Boot Web

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Using a Spring Boot web application I trying to serve my static resource from a file system folder outside my project.

Folder structure looks like:-

```
          src
             main
                 java
                 resources
             test
                 java
                 resources
          pom.xml
          ext-resources   (I want to keep my static resources here)
                 test.js
```

Spring Configuration:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoStaticresourceApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoStaticresourceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/test/**").addResourceLocations("file:///./ext-resources/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);
    }
}
```

Hitting 'http://localhost:9999/test/test.js' in my browser gives back a 404.

How should I configure ResourceHandlerRegistry to serve static resources from the above mentioned 'ext-resources' folder?

I should be able to switch cache on/off for dev/prod environment.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

Giving absolute file path works:-

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/test/**")
                .addResourceLocations(
                        "file:///C:/Sambhav/Installations/workspace/demo-staticresource/ext-resources/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);
}
```

How can I provide relative location? Absolute path will make my life tough during build & deploy process.

Comment: have you tried absolute path? (and maybe you just have one `/` more in your URL :))

Comment: Absolute path works. See updated question. Is there any way of providing relative path?

Comment: build it :) e.g. File("ext-resource").getAbsoluteFile().toURI... check javadoc for proper syntax

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`file:///` is an absolute URL pointing to the root of the filesystem and, therefore, `file:///./ext-resources/` means that Spring Boot is looking for resources in a directory named `ext-resources` in the root.

Update your configuration to use something like `file:ext-resources/` as the URL.

Comment: FYI... `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated in 5.0 of spring.  They recommend using `WebMvcConfigurer` for your mvc configuration.

Comment: I'll note that the paths are relative to where where the app was started, not to where the jar file resides. Example: for java -jar ./target/app.jar, relative paths start above the target directory.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did in the WebConfig class, inside the addResourceHandlers method:

```
boolean devMode = this.env.acceptsProfiles("development");
String location;
if (devMode) {
    String currentPath = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
    location = "file:///" + currentPath + "/client/src/";
} else {
    location = "classpath:static/";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot Maven Plugin can add extra directories to the classpath. In your case you could include that in your pom.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <folders>
            <folder>${project.build.directory}/../ext-resources</folder>
        </folders>

        ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So that way you don't need inlcude any hard-code in your classes. Simply start your webapp with

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Answer (score 2):

`static resources (eg:html js css etc)` can be placed in the same level directory of project or jar, named `public`. contents will be servered without additional config.